# trouble animating transition AND removing elements in D3

Tags: d3.js

My goal is to allow the end user to toggle between two histograms using update functions that run on clicks.

I can successfully update the histogram using the following two functions (one for each dataset).  However, I can only figure out how to either 
1) remove the existing rects and replace them with new rects with the updated data in a very abrupt manner OR
2) animate the transition smoothly between the two datasets but fail to remove the first set of rects.

The D3 visualization can be seen here:  http://jackielu.github.io/d3-hist-v3/

When you click on "Percent Impervious" the histogram updates correctly but abruptly and inelegantly.
When you click on "Percent Canopy" the histogram updates with a nice transition BUT the previous set of rects remains

The code that runs when "Percent Impervious" is clicked is as follows:

```
function drawChartImperv(data) {

  //grab the values you need and bin them
  histogramData = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(xScale.ticks(10))
    (data.features.map(function (d) {
        return d.properties.Imperv_P}));

  window.histogramData = histogramData;

  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(histogramData, function(d) { return d.y; })])
    .nice();
  yAxis.scale(yScale);
  yAxis2.call(yAxis);

  xAxis2.select(".xLabel")
    .text("Impervious Percentage")

  bar.remove();

  //bind the data once
  bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(histogramData)

  //handle new elements
  bar.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xScale(d.x) + "," + yScale(d.y) + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", function (d) { (height - padding) - yScale(d.y);})
      .attr("width", xScale(histogramData[0].dx)/2)
      .attr("height", function (d) { return (height - padding) - yScale(d.y); })
      //color the bars using the color function for the layer
      .style("fill", "#309195")

    // handle updated elements
  bar.transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xScale(d.x) + "," + yScale(d.y) + ")"; });

    // handle removed elements
  bar.exit()
    .remove();
}
```

The code that allows a smooth transition but does not remove the old rects is:

```
function drawChartCan(data){

  //grab the values you need and bin them
  histogramData = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(xScale.ticks(10))
    (data.features.map(function (d) {
        return d.properties.Can_P}));

  window.histogramData = histogramData;

  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(histogramData, function(d) { return d.y; })])
    .nice();
  yAxis.scale(yScale);
  yAxis2.call(yAxis);


  xAxis2.select(".xLabel")
    .text("Canopy Percentage")

  //bind the data once
  bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(histogramData)

  //handle new elements
  bar.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xScale(d.x) + "," + yScale(d.y) + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", function (d) { (height - padding) - yScale(d.y);})
      .attr("width", xScale(histogramData[0].dx)/2)
      .attr("height", function (d) { return (height - padding) - yScale(d.y); })
      //color the bars using the color function for the layer
      .style("fill", "#41ab5d")

    // handle updated elements
  bar.transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xScale(d.x) + "," + yScale(d.y) + ")"; })

    // handle removed elements
  bar.exit()
    .remove();
}
```

The only difference between the two code blocks is that in the `drawChartImperv` function there is a `bar.remove()` statement after the Y and X axes are updated.

I suspect the `bar.remove()` statement is in the wrong place in my `drawChartImperv` function but I can't figure out where it should be so that I can have a nice transition between the two sets of bars, AND remove the old rects?

Full code is here:  https://github.com/jackielu/d3-hist-v3

All suggestions and hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the two bar charts will have the same number of bars? See if these resources are helpful: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/ and https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#enter

Comment: it is not guaranteed that the two bar charts will have the same number of bars, unfortunately - this is a simplification of code only showing two data properties - there are a total of 10 that i want to use in the project, so need to account for all the scenarios! thanks for the resources I will take a look